# Tag autocomplete: "svgjs" should find [svg.js]

Tags: feature-request, tags

Most JavaScript libraries end with "js" some use ".js" some only "js".

It would be nice that if you enter "svgjs" the tag [svg.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg.js) gets found.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a synonym, so you should rephrase your question into a proper [synonym-request].

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I am lazy. I dont' want to create 100 synonyms. There are many JS-Libs. I think "foojs" should match "foo.js" (if it exists).